# Unable to use git in shell inside a buffer

Tags: spacemacs, osx, git

I used 'M-x shell' to start a shell inside a buffer. Then I tried to run git diff

[image]

After I press the space bar a few time, the `lines 29-69/69` line is printed a few and the shell has stopped responding.

Why it is the case? Is there anything to fix it?

**EDIT**

Did not see this error message when I used shell last time:

[image]

(*I alias `g` to `git`*)

Now I am not able to use `git diff` at all.

Comment: `M-x shell` or something else?

Comment: That's how I started the shell

Comment: `M-x shell` is a dumb terminal, whereas it looks like the commands you're using are wanting a more full-functional terminal. In this case, it might just be wanting to invoke a pager. You could set your `GIT_PAGER` environment variable, or the `core.pager` git config option. Or else just use an actual terminal emulator instead of `shell-mode`. Emacs has one built in: `M-x term` (or `ansi-term`).

Comment: @phils I think `M-x term` is the answer. If you can post it as an answer to this question, i will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`M-x shell` is a dumb terminal, whereas it looks like the commands you're using expect a more fully-featured terminal. This is what the "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" messages are about.

To circumvent the general issue, you could use a proper terminal emulator instead of `shell-mode`. Emacs has one built in: `M-x term` (or `M-x ansi-term`).

---

Note that git might just be wanting to invoke a pager. So another approach would be to tell git not to use paged output, via the `GIT_PAGER` environment variable, or the `core.pager` git config option.

You could test this in the shell like so:

```sh
git --no-pager diff
```

or using the environment variable:

```sh
GIT_PAGER=cat git diff
```

or configure it permanently:

```sh
git config core.pager cat
git diff
```

Comment: I'll add that if using `cat` as the 'pager' for git like this, you may very well also wish to limit the number of lines of output for certain git commands, otherwise you may get a *lot* of output dumped into the buffer.  e.g. `git log` provides an option  to "Limit the number of commits to output." with can be specified with any of `-<number>, -n <number>, --max-count=<number>`

Comment: Or alternatively, you might use `head` (or a command which calls `head` with some custom max line-count argument) as your pager, instead of `cat`, and then use `--no-pager` in cases when you wish to *disable* that default limitation.

Comment: *Personally* I'd recommend using Magit, though (over any other approach to using git within Emacs).